# Theano shared variable vs numpy array speed in theano function

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm learning about theano, and trying to implement a modular ML tool with it.

I've a simple linear combination with:

```
    w = th.shared(np.ones([input_size, output_size], dtype=th.config.floatX),
                  name='W',
                  borrow=True)
    x = T.dmatrix('x')
    dot = T.dot(x, w)
```

but now I'm a little confused about the best way to describe the `dot` as a theano function. I came up with two functions:

```
dot1 = th.function([x], dot)
dot2 = th.function([], dot, givens={x: self.input_data})
```

where `input_data` is a shared variable.

My goal is to run it on GPUs, so I'd like to use shared variables as much as possible.

The problem is that, if I use the `dot1` function, I cannot use a shared variable in the input. And when using the `dot2`, the only way I got it working is reading as numpy arrays and constantly updating the `self.input_data` with `set_value()`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17296524/2877599)

My question is: What is the best, `dot1` or `dot2` to run on gpus ?